# RadioButton Uncheck events not firing in WPF?

Tags: wpf

In my WPF Window i have RadioButton with default IsChecked property is true.
How to write code for Uncheck the RadioButton.
I tried with Sipmle example.
I take one radiobutton.

```
    <Grid>
    <RadioButton Height="16" Margin="54,103,104,0" GroupName="t" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Unchecked="radioButton1_Unchecked">Text</RadioButton>
</Grid>

 private void radioButton1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.IsChecked = false;
    }
```

But its not working
Can any one help on this?

Ramki

Comment: you asked 14 questions and have not marked one as answered...

Comment: Your title says one thing and your question says another. When do you want to uncheck the radio button?

Comment: Also, since you only have one RadioButton maybe you want a Checkbox?

Comment: Why uncheck in the unchecked event?  What is the question?

Comment: Consider a scenario where you want to be able to select only one item in a group or none. To achieve that, you can either use check-boxes and write code to make sure only one is checked at one time or use radiobuttons and write code to deselect the selected radiobutton. And yes, there is a way to deselect a radio button without selecting another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is not possible to uncheck a radiobutton that is singled out. It would make no sense. That's why your event doesn't get fired.

Now, having a single RadioButton will not help you achieve anything: they are meant to be in a group of RadioButtons. Use a CheckBox instead.

Then in the UnChecked event, you don't have to uncheck it: the event is fired because it was unchecked in the first place =)

```
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Height="16" Margin="54,103,104,0" GroupName="t" Name="checkBox1"
VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="True" Unchecked="checkBox1_Unchecked">Text</CheckBox>
    </Grid>

     private void checkBox1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("checkBox1 has been unchecked!");
        }
```

Comment: thanks for giving reply.Now i know my mistake.Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 0):

you can't Uncheck a radiobutton if you haven"t another to check !